# show/hide D3 element based on mouse in/mouse out

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two elements here. points and labels (I am using D3)

As i mouseover the points element I would like it show the label element related to that particular point. As I mouse out I want the label to disappear.

Currently when I mouseover, ALL the labels appear (not just the one for that point) and when I mouse out the labels disappear but are never triggered when I mouseover a second time. I am beginner so thanks for any help.

```
points
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return scaleX(d[0]); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return scaleY(d[1]); })
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('fill', 'slateBlue')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3
            .select(this)
            .attr('fill', 'hotpink');            
        labels
            .text(function(d) { return d[0] + ',' + d[1]; })
            .attr('x', function(d) { return scaleX(d[0]) + 3; })
            .attr('y', function(d) { return scaleY(d[1]) - 3; })
            .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
            .attr('font-size', '10px')
            .attr('fill', 'hotpink');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3
            .select(this)
            .attr('fill', 'slateBlue');
        labels
            .remove();
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `d3.select(this)`and only modify the `labels`?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. You have to show us what's the relationship with `points` and `labels`, so we can think about a way to filter the label. The most common approach would be binding the data to `<g>` elements, so you could easily deal with circles and texts for the same datum.

Answer (score 0):

When you .remove() labels, the nodes are removed from the DOM. You can’t update their text() anymore because there is no node to update. I’d suggest simply:  labels.attr(“display”, “none”) to hide and labels.attr(“display”,null) to show.